# ¿En dónde y cómo se utiliza await en Python?

Tags: python, async-await

Quería saber si alguien me puede explicar el uso de "await x" en Python. No sé el uso práctico de esa expresión.

```
a la espera

    Es un objeto a la espera (awaitable) que puede ser usado en una expresión await. Puede ser una coroutine o un objeto con un método __await__(). Vea también PEP 492.
```

6.4. Expresión await

Suspende la ejecución de coroutine o un objeto awaitable. Puede ser usado sólo dentro de una coroutine function.

await_expr ::=  "await" primary

Nuevo en la versión 3.5.

Comment: Sólo puedes usarlo si utilizas programación asíncrona, lo cual requiere el apoyo de una biblioteca asíncrona. La más típicamente utilizada (porque viene ya con python) es `asyncio`. Tienes que usar esa biblioteca para crear tareas asíncronas y lograr que se ejecuten. Entonces `await` puede ser usada dentro de una de esas tareas para cuando desde ella se invoca otra asíncrona y se quiere esperar a obtener la respuesta (pero sin detener el bucle de eventos principal)

Comment: En pocas palabras, si no sabes lo que es programación asíncrona y no te interesa, olvídate de `await`. Si te interesa, tendrás que leer la documentación de `asyncio`, y prepararte para que el cerebro se te convierta en spaghetti durante unos días hasta que lo vayas pillando.

Comment: [Async IO in Python: A Complete Walkthrough](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)